# execve to file I just wrote -- "Text file busy"

Tags: c, linux, execve

The intended behavior of the C program below is to copy its own executable file to a new randomly-named file, then execve that file, ad nauseum. This should create many, many copies of the executable. This is obviously a terrible idea, but it is nevertheless what I am trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  /* Obtain name of current executable */
  const char* binName = argv[0];

  /* Print message */
  printf("Hello from %s!\n", binName);

  /* Create name of new executable */
  char newBinName[] = "tmpXXXXXX";
  mkstemp(newBinName);

  /* Determine size of current executable */
  struct stat st;
  stat(binName, &st);
  const int binSize = st.st_size;

  /* Copy current executable to memory */
  char* binData = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * binSize);
  FILE* binFile = fopen(binName, "rb");
  fread(binData, sizeof(char), binSize, binFile);
  fclose(binFile);

  /* Write executable in memory to new file */
  binFile = fopen(newBinName, "wb");
  fwrite(binData, sizeof(char), binSize, binFile);
  fclose(binFile);

  /* Make new file executable */
  chmod(newBinName, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR |S_IXUSR);

  /* Run new file executable */
  execve(
    newBinName,
    (char*[]) {
      newBinName,
      NULL
    },
    NULL);

  /* If this code runs, then there has been an error. */
  perror("execve");

  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Instead, though, the following is output:

```
Hello from ./execTest
execve: Text file busy
```

I presume that the text file is "busy" because `./execTest` is still accessing it... but I do close the file stream to that file. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

From the [manpage of `mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html):

```
   On success, these functions return the file descriptor of the
   temporary file.
```

You discard the file descriptor returned to you by `mkstemp`, effectively leaking it.  Probably it is a writable file descriptor and thus will cause `execve` to fail with `ETXTBSY` (which occurs when there are writable fds open).  Can you try `close()` on the return value of `mkstemp` and see if that improves the behavior?

<sub>General point of feedback: When coding in C you should be in the habit of looking at return values. Failure to observe their meaning and error status is often indicative of a bug.</sub>

Comment: Oh, bloody... yes, that was exactly it, thank you. I'm a C++ programmer; I'm still fumbling a bit with the C stuff.